# How do I add shell programs to the Unity search results?

Tags: unity, java

When you add no-install applications to Ubuntu, they don't come up in the Unity search. For example, I downloaded Eclipse and unzipped it in a folder: `~/SelfInstall/eclipse`.

How do I get `eclipse` which is located in `~/SelfInstall/eclipse/` to show up in the search results?

**Update:**

Ah, if I add a 'desktop configuration file' to `.local/share/applications` and point it to the launch script, then it works, but I don't know how to create a file of type 'desktop configuration file'. I had to copy one and edit it's properties. Any idea on how to create these files from scratch?

**Update 2:**

Ok, so this is how the file had to look:

```
cat .local/share/applications/opt_eclipse.desktop 

[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Icon=/home/me/SelfInstall/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/home/me/SelfInstall/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop/66918#66918

Comment: Found a nice related tutorial: http://hanynowsky.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/eclipse-ides-ubuntu-integrated-menus-hack/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create, or copy an existing .desktop file, for the application, into your `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications` directory.

Comment: Thanks, and now I know how to create a desktop configuration file.... just add .desktop. Blonde moment there